# Lightning Wallet (lnd) - Export Private/Public Keys?

Tags: wallet, lightning-network-daemon

Is it possible to export keys from a Lightning Wallet, specifically lnd? I started opening my first channels, and most of what I'm reading says that you want to monitor your wallet balance (in the absence of watchtowers, which aren't implemented yet). I was looking to get the public key for my Lightning wallet so I can have a watching-only copy. I suppose I can do that by just having the address with some wallets, but it would also be nice to have the raw private keys for backup.

I know how to get the keys out of a normal bitcoin wallet, but not sure how to do that with lnd, since they're stored in `wallet.db`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is not possible. They are still working on it.

https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/732

Comment: It looks like it's not possible with just lnd, but seems possible with [chantools](https://github.com/guggero/chantools)?